# How to implement bootstrap Tabs and Collapse menu at a same time?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried implementing bootstrap tabs and inside tabs BOOTSTRAP COLLAPSE.

For tabs, I implemented:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
 {  
//Redirecciona al tab, usando un prefijo al cargar por primera vez, al usar redirect en cake #_Pagos    
//Redirecciona al tab, usando #Pagos
/* Automagically jump on good tab based on anchor; for page reloads or links */
 if(location.hash) 
  {
     $('a[href=' + location.hash + ']').tab('show');         
  }


//Para evitar el bajar al nivel del tab, (al mostrarse el tab subimos)
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) 
{
    location.hash = $(e.target).attr('href').substr(1);
    scrollTo(0,0);      
});



//Actualiza el URL con el anchor o ancla del tab al darle clic
 /* Update hash based on tab, basically restores browser default behavior to
 fix bootstrap tabs */
$(document.body).on("click", "a[data-toggle]", function(event) 
  {
    location.hash = this.getAttribute("href");
  });


//Redirecciona al tab, al usar los botones de regresar y avanzar del navegador.
/* on history back activate the tab of the location hash if exists or the default tab if no hash exists */   
$(window).on('popstate', function() 
{
  //Si se accesa al menu, se regresa al tab del perfil (activo default), fixed conflict with menu
  //var anchor = location.hash || $("a[data-toggle=tab]").first().attr("href");
  var anchor = location.hash;
  $('a[href=' + anchor + ']').tab('show');

});   

});//Fin OnReady
</script>
```

but whenever I click COLLAPSE, the page scroll up. Is there anyway, I can use both efficiently.

This is the link: http://custmr.co.uk/industry-specific/

After we click "real estate", we can go to collapse.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss prevent the "anchor" default event;

Ex:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "a[data-toggle]", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    location.hash = this.getAttribute("href");
  });
```

FYI

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

The "event click" in anchor elements call by default the same page like `<a href="#">some foo</a>`

No se por que lo escribí en inglés si tus comentarios del código están en español.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented preventDefault but still the same problem. Do you know where do I have to correct? Sorry for spanish comment, I found the code from some forum.